# How to change the Oculus Rift "Tracker sensor" device in the Framework?

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, windows-10, oculus

I wan't to turn off the "reset position" when the Tracking sensor has moved 22.5 degrees.

We are a company who build a device for walking in scénes. At times we want to rotate the "Tracking sensor" around the player.
Every time we do that now, the "Tracking sensor" device reset the hmd. This gives a stutter and resets the tracking sensor to the north.

We use Unity 5.4.0f2 in Windows 10 now. We already tried to turn it off in Unity, but this isn't possible.

How can we disable the function in the Oculus framework?

Comment: Have you tried setting `OVRManager.usePositionTracking` to `false` while the camera is moving, or is that what you tried when you said "*We already tried to turn it off in Unity*"? No idea if it will help at all, just a thought.

Comment: Also, if you have not done it yet, ask this question on the [Unity subsection of the Oculus developer forums](https://forums.oculus.com/developer/categories/unity), you are much more likely to get a useful answer there. If you do be sure to come back here and post a answer to your own question explaining what you had to do and mark it accepted.

Comment: we used OVRManager.usePositionTrackingbut it sets the whole camera to turn off.

We already asked the Oculus and Unity developers, but they haven't any answers.

Answer (score 0):

IFixit [states that there is also a magnetometer](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Oculus+Rift+CV1+Teardown/60612), so just rotating the camera is not enough - you would have to fool the magnetometer too. And probably gyros. This doesn't seem doable without heavily modifying the rift's hardware of firmware.

You might want to rethink your method - why do you need to rotate the camera in the first place? The rift is visible from all directions, so there should be no need for it (see [this image](http://img1.lesnumeriques.com/news/51/51085/oculus-rift-cv1-ifixit-05.jpg) from [this thread](https://reddit.com/r/oculus/comments/4fhyaz/facing_directly_away_from_the_cv1_sensor_not/)).

Perhaps you only want to rotate the direction where the user is facing? This might be best to do in the software/content, assuming it's dedicated for your hardware.

Comment: When we put a cover on the Sensor, it won't do anything, and also won't reset the position after 22.5 degrees. The magnetometer isn't the problem. The sensor gets it's position from the oculus, but when the degrees from the oculus don't match with its position, the reset will activate itself. We want that line of script gone.